# Illustrator CS6 ".ai" replaced by ".pdf" when Save As PDF

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, file-format

I have a strange issue, happening for a few hours(don't know how I did that):

- I'm in "myflie.ai" -> Save As PDF(any Preset)->File is saved -> "myfile.ai" is replaced by "myfile.pdf" in Illustrator automatically.(it's very annoying when I modify again my file and I see that I modified the **.pdf** not the **.ai** file)

Why this happens and how can I solve this?
Thank you!

Comment: You should know there's no real difference between an .ai file and a .pdf file. So why does it matter?

Comment: @LateralTerminal - it is for texts(it converts each word or so in objects with fixed size), also if you open pdf in AI it will make a clipping mask for all layers...anyways I want to edit my `.ai` file not the generated pdf

Comment: There **is** a difference between .ai and .pdf. Sometimes a *really* important difference.

Comment: @Scott do you have any citations? Because I've really tried to research deep into this one and haven't found anything. I've found that as long as you "maintain editing" in the settings then it's fine.

Comment: @LateralTerminal  see here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/104536/saving-working-files-as-psd-or-tiff/104541#104541 Same reason for PDF vs AI. File corruption can happen **any** time for **any** reason.

Comment: @LateralTerminal the PDF is not the AI file its just that the AI is embedded in the PDF file. So in AI it looks the same, but the file itsel is different depending om sittings... Offcourse you can remove the AI settings and then you will see it

Comment: I think I must be misunderstanding this question. Are you asking why _Save as PDF_ saves the file as a PDF? What else would you expect it to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have an AI file open, then click ***File > Save a Copy*** instead, then choose the PDF file type.

If you do that, Illustrator simply exports the file as a PDF, and doesn't open the PDF automatically. The AI file will still be open in Illustrator.

It's super annoying if you forget to do that, and accidentally hit *Save As* (which I frequently do). If you do make that mistake, just close the PDF, and open the AI - it should be listed under *Open Recent Files*.

As to "why?" - that's a question only Adobe can truly answer.  Why make this so counter-intuitive? Why not have the functionality to export a PDF within the normal *Export* option?

Comment: + @WELZ -  so this is not a new one, maybe now I've seen it - but I remember that this doesn't happened before...I'm confused - Thanks for your time guys!

Comment: I always.. save... save as (PDF)... undo.. Now I'm back to the AI file if needed. If the undo fails for some reason, then I can open the ai file from the Recent items. The important thing is to save.. before saving as a pdf to retain all the ai editing info.

Answer (score 2):

As it is one of the Illustrator file types (ai, svg, eps, pdf etc.) it is just being saved and that makes it switch from the current file.

-I know it can be annoying (happens to me sometimes as well)

If you were to *Export* your file, that would save the file and you would continue to be able to work on it. Unfortunately, there's no option to "Export" as a pdf, maybe Illustrator will fix that one day.

A (slightly inconvenient) solution/workaround would be to just hit **File** → **Open Recent Files** and just open the .ai file. (You can then close the pdf from your workspace)